# File bluetooth visibilty default on

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, bluetooth, files, file-transfer

I have a Galaxy S II, I transfer files using bluetooth to my PC all the time, constantly! It's rather annoying having to mark each and every file as visible on bluetooth (very stupid design not allowing the user to mark this as default if they want to) and also time consuming having to do each and every file be it image or what have you.

Is there any way to make all files default to bluetooth on? Be it a hack or what have you I just need to be able to set all files default to that.

Answer (score 2):

[Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp) can be good if you want to initiate the transfer from the mobile Device. However, since I won't to transfer file to and from PC/Mac, I prefer using PC/Mac to control which files I want to put/get. It is easier, quicker, and I don't have to fight with small device to properly check/uncheck files.

Basic settings like 'all files visible via BT' would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t had the need for any "hacks", I use [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp) by Medieval Software available for free from Google Play Store.

With this app, I can copy an entire folder or select and copy the desired files. Then, just past them into the bluetooth tab and voila, they start transferring to the computer.

> Bluetooth File Transfer (OBEX FTP and OPP) for Android
>
> Use your smartphone to browse, explore and manage files of any Bluetooth ready device, using File Transfer Profile (FTP) and Object Push Profile (OPP): you can also receive files and send contacts!

[image: Multiple Select Screeshoot]